# Play Sounds From Raw File in Kotlin

Tags: android, audio, kotlin

I create Application Sounds Of Animals 
But I have a Problem The Sounds are not playing
The Code of list of Animals with Name , Image and Sound

```
 listanimales.add(animals("Cat",R.drawable.a1,R.raw.a1))
 listanimales.add(animals("Dog",R.drawable.a2,R.raw.a2))
 listanimales.add(animals("Fox",R.drawable.a3,R.raw.a3))
```

```
override fun getView(postion: Int, p1: View?, p2: ViewGroup?): View? {
    var anum = mylistofAnimals[postion]
    var myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.design,null)
       myView.anImage.setImageResource(anum.aImage!!)
      myView.anName.text = anum.aName!!
        myView.anImage.setOnClickListener {
        player = MediaPlayer()
            try {

                player!!.setDataSource(anum.aSound)
                player!!.prepare()
                player!!.start()
            }catch (ex:Exception){
            }
        }
        return myView
    }
```

The End is my Class

```
class animals{
var aName:String?=null
var aImage:Int?=null
var aSound:Int?=null
constructor(aName:String,aImage:Int,aSound:Int){
this.aName = aName
this.aImage = aImage
this.aSound = aSound
}
```

}

What's the Problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try using the following code in kotlin:

```
player = MediaPlayer()
player.create(this,anum.aSound)
player!!.start()
```

the below code is converted from java to kotlin. Hope it can also run.

EDIT: acc to @bakawali suggestion instead of this use `view` to get `context`.

```
val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mView.Context, resID)
mediaPlayer.start()
```

Where your resID will be as follow:

```
var resID = getResources().getIdentifier(anum.aSound, "raw", getPackageName())
```

make sure anum.aSound is just the name of the sound with no extension

Example:
Sound file : ringtone.mp3 - write:

```
.getIndentifier("ringtone","raw",getPackageName())
```

Comment: I have problem with .create()

Comment: The Error is create is has red line , I think because in my adapter I get another Activity  you can see this line  : `    var myView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.design,null)
`

Comment: `this` should be referred to a `Context` object. Try `player.create(mView.context ,anum.aSound)` or reference to the context in other way.

Answer (score 3):

The above answer helped me but this is what worked for me in my current project. I hope it helps someone else in the near future.

```
 fun playSound() {

        var resId = getResources().getIdentifier(R.raw.sawing.toString(),
            "raw", activity?.packageName)

        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(activity, resId)
        mediaPlayer.start()
    }
```

sawing is the name of my file in the raw folder.
I am using this function inside a fragment. 
If you don't understand Ill happily explain.

Answer (score 2):

fun playPhrase(view: View) {
val buttonPressed: Button = view as Button
Toast.makeText(this, buttonPressed.getTag().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

```
    val mplayer: MediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resources.getIdentifier(
            buttonPressed.tag.toString(), "raw", packageName))
    mplayer.start()
}
```

Using "android:tag="mysound" to play sound